# How to configure Camel CXF with Basic authentication

Tags: java, cxf, apache-camel

I'm new to Apache Camel and CXF,

I'm trying to create a route for querying a remote WS which requires Basic Authentication and to specify the Soap Action header.

I was able to achieve the same using camel HTTP component but i needed the same with camel CXF
in  java DSL

Can anyone guide us in fixing the same

Comment: You can simply create a POJO to invoke the service and use it as bean in your route. The POJO itself may contain f.e. a [CXF WebClient](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.html) which offers a [factory method for basic authentication](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.html#create%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks for the response , Can you please provide us some sample code to achieve the same eg for http component we have authMethod=Basic --->  from("direct:routes"). 
         to("http://localhost/whatever?authMethod=Basic&authUsername=me&authPassword=secret");    can we have a similar example to like above for CXF webclient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use camel-cxf component to setup the Basic authentication, you need do some configuration on the CxfEndpoint just like this.

```
CxfEndpoint cxfEndpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint(“cxf:xxx”); 
// set the authentication information 
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 

org.apache.cxf.configuration.security.AuthorizationPolicy authPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy(); 
authPolicy.setUserName(username); 
authPolicy.setPassword(password); 
properties.put(AuthorizationPolicy.class.getName(), authPolicy); 

cxfEndpoint.setProperties(properties);     

from(“xxx”).to(cxfEndpoint);
```

Answer (score 1):

With @Willem's help, was able to make this working. The authentication credentials need to passed to the CXF Endpoint in the Route Builder rather than in the Processor. This is as explained by Williem on Camel forum:

> If you set the cxfEndpoint property in a processor, it’s a setting of runtime.
>   As the CxfProducer is created during the camel context start the route, the cxfEndpoint’s property is >not updated.

So, to fix this add the following code to the Route Builder:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 

AuthorizationPolicy authPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy(); 
authPolicy.setAuthorizationType(HttpAuthHeader.AUTH_TYPE_BASIC); 
authPolicy.setUserName(USERNAME); 
authPolicy.setPassword(PWD); 
authPolicy.setAuthorization("true");

//properties.put(AuthorizationPolicy.class.getName(), authPolicy);
properties.put("org.apache.cxf.configuration.security.AuthorizationPolicy", authPolicy);

CxfEndpoint myCxfEp = (CxfEndpoint)getContext().getEndpoint("cxf://");
myCxfEp.setProperties(properties);
```

Also, in version 2.12.3 of Apache Camel is introducing username and password options for basic authentication.

Comment: Yeah, you can set the username, password option on the CXF endpoint uri just like  "cxf://bean:myservice?username=user1&password=pass"    in Camel 2.13.x.

Answer (score 0):

In current versions of camel-cxf it should be sufficient to set username and password directly on CxfEndpoint:

```
cxfEndpoint.setUsername("xyz");
csfEndpoint.setPassword("verySecure");
```

I just looked into the code of CxfEndpoint and found:

```
// setup the basic authentication property
if (ObjectHelper.isNotEmpty(username)) {
    AuthorizationPolicy authPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy();
    authPolicy.setUserName(username);
    authPolicy.setPassword(password);
    factoryBean.getProperties().put(AuthorizationPolicy.class.getName(), authPolicy);
}
```

So if you set username, basic auth will be configured as shown in other answers.