# Apache Camel v2.12 | CXF Component | Basic Authentication

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, cxf, apache-camel

Respected Experts,

I am trying to access a web service that requires basic authentication. I am able to access using the CXF's JaxWsDynamicClientFactory. The code piece for auth looks like:

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = dcf.createClient(ID_WSDL);

HTTPConduit conduit= (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
AuthorizationPolicy authorization =  conduit.getAuthorization();
authorization.setUserName(USERNAME);
authorization.setPassword(PWD);

conduit.setAuthorization(authorization);
```

However, when I try to use Camel's CXF component to access the same Web Service I get 401 Unauthorized error, since Camel is not sending the authentication information to the Web Service.

My route looks like:

```
from("file://c:/test?fileName=request.txt&noop=true").routeId("myrouteId")
.process(processor)
.to(cxf)
.to("log:{body}");
```

In my processor, I am setting the credentials as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

AuthorizationPolicy authPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy();
authPolicy.setAuthorizationType(HttpAuthHeader.AUTH_TYPE_BASIC);
authPolicy.setUserName(USERNAME);
authPolicy.setPassword(PWD);

properties.put("org.apache.cxf.configuration.security.AuthorizationPolicy", authPolicy);
myEndpoint.setProperties(properties);
```

myEndpoint is CXFEndpoint, retrieved from Exchange.

Am I missing something or something wrong here.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948182/how-to-configure-camel-cxf-with-basic-authentication). I had raised my doubt there as a answer since I was not able to comment. However, my answer has been deleted. So, I am raising a fresh question in a hope that I will get some direction to move forward on this.

Thks & brgds

Answer (score 1):

With Willem's help, was able to make this working. The authentication credentials need to passed to the CXF Endpoint in the Route Builder rather than in the Processor. This is as explained by Williem on Camel forum:

> If you set the cxfEndpoint property in a processor, it’s a setting of runtime.
>   As the CxfProducer is created during the camel context start the route, the cxfEndpoint’s property is >not updated.

So, to fix this add the following code to the Route Builder:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 

AuthorizationPolicy authPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy(); 
authPolicy.setAuthorizationType(HttpAuthHeader.AUTH_TYPE_BASIC); 
authPolicy.setUserName(USERNAME); 
authPolicy.setPassword(PWD); 
authPolicy.setAuthorization("true");

//properties.put(AuthorizationPolicy.class.getName(), authPolicy);
properties.put("org.apache.cxf.configuration.security.AuthorizationPolicy", authPolicy);

CxfEndpoint myCxfEp = (CxfEndpoint)getContext().getEndpoint("cxf://");
myCxfEp.setProperties(properties);
```

Also, version 2.12.3 of Apache Camel is introducing username and password options for basic authentication.